# Making a procedural spring clamp using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, mathematics

Making a procedural spring clamp using geometry nodes.

I can design / create a spring clamp in blender (see image below)

[image: img1]

I would like to make it more procedural using geometry nodes (so I would have the ability to adjust it more accurately).  **I can adjust the height but would also like the ability to change the curve diameter at the top, the middle diameter, and it's length** (**see arrows**).

[image: img2]

I can adjust things using the **scale element node** but it's not really exact (**example: trying to change the diameter of the center section to hold a 5mm diameter object**). Do I need to recreate the spring clamp from scratch using geometry nodes to allow this?

The reason for exacting dimensions is that this will be 3D printed.

[image: img]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Attached file:
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't do this in geometry nodes.  Or at least, not primarily in GN.  A curve object gives you the minimum number of parameters, in a method more easily edited (perhaps, with drivers or hooks.)  Then you give it curve extrusion or a bevel object and a boolean.  You might need GN for the boolean, but that alone.  You end up with something just as editable, but editable in a more convenient fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to solve this with *Geometry Nodes*, then I would use a Bezier curve as a starting point.

By scaling this curve and then extruding it, you get a mesh that is not only changeable in all directions, but also generated with a uniform thickness independent of the scaling of the curve.

So the order should be:

- First scale
- Then create a base (thickness) with `Curve to Mesh`
- Then extrude to height
- And finally cut with the cylinder

In addition, you can always influence the resolution of the mesh.

The solution could therefore look like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>